# Objects not Extruding in MEL

Tags: 3d, maya, mel

I am attempting to control extrusion of an object via rotation of another object in MAYA. But for some reason it's not working. It keeps showing I am getting a syntax error. i am not sure what is wrong with it or how to fix it?

This is the code for it:

```
int $totalObjects = 1; 
polyPipe -n Rotator -ch on -o on -r 1.839239 -h 1.223879 ;
polyExtrudeFacet -constructionHistory 1 -keepFacesTogether 1 -pvx 0.07364761256 -pvy 0.6119394158 -pvz 4.019784712 -divisions 1 -twist 0 -taper 1 -off 0 -thickness 0 -smoothingAngle 30 Rotator.f[36];
setAttr "polyExtrudeFace1.localTranslate" -type double3 0 0 0.930651 ;


string $controlName = "Rotator";

float $spacing = 1.5;

for($i=1;$i<=$totalObjects;$i++)
{

 string $outName = ("twist_"+ $i);   
 string $outNameExtrude = ("ext_"+$i);
 float $extrusion = 0;

polyCube -n $outName -ch on -o on -w 12.009218 -h 7.720124 -d 0.755927 -cuv 4 ;
setAttr ($outName+".translateZ") ($spacing*$i);  


expression -s ($extrusion +"= Rotator.rotateY * 0.01*" + ($i*0.5) + ";")  -o "" -ae 1 -uc all ;


polyExtrudeFacet -n $outNameExtrude -constructionHistory 1 -keepFacesTogether 1 -pvx 0 -pvy 0 -pvz 4.0 -r $outName ;
setAttr $outNameExtrude + ".localTranslate" -type double3 0 $extrusion 0 ;


}
```

---

UPDATED:

```
int $totalObjects = 1; 
polyPipe -n Rotator -ch on -o on -r 1.839239 -h 1.223879 ;
polyExtrudeFacet -constructionHistory 1 -keepFacesTogether 1 -pvx 0.07364761256 -pvy 0.6119394158 -pvz 4.019784712 -divisions 1 -twist 0 -taper 1 -off 0 -thickness 0 -smoothingAngle 30 Rotator.f[36];
setAttr "polyExtrudeFace1.localTranslate" -type double3 0 0 0.930651 ;


string $controlName = "Rotator";

float $spacing = 1.5;

for($i=1;$i<=$totalObjects;$i++)
{

 string $outName = ("twist_"+ $i);   
 string $outNameExtrude = ("ext_"+$i);
 float $extrusion = 0;

polyCube -n $outName -ch on -o on -w 12.009218 -h 7.720124 -d 0.755927 -cuv 4 ;
setAttr ($outName+".translateZ") ($spacing*$i);  



polyExtrudeFacet -n $outNameExtrude -constructionHistory 1 -keepFacesTogether 1 -pvx 0 -pvy 0 -pvz 4.0 $outName ;
setAttr ($outNameExtrude + ".localTranslate") -type double3 0 $extrusion 0 ;


expression -s ( $outNameExtrude + ".O[0]" +"= Rotator.rotateY * 0.01*" + ($i*0.5) + ";")  -o "" -ae 1 -uc all ;


}
```

Comment: Why is it tagged [tag:python]?

Comment: @hus787 Yeah the tag should be removed, suggested edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @theodox. You should never rely on Maya setting the name you told it to set. Because if Maya has a naming clash, etc. than maya will override you so whenever you create something always catch the name. So for example

```
polyExtrudeFacet -n $outNameExtrude 
                 -ch 1 -keepFacesTogether 1 
                 -pvx 0 -pvy 0 -pvz 4.0 $outName;
```

Should be:

```
$tmp = `polyExtrudeFacet -n $outNameExtrude
                         -ch 1 
                         -keepFacesTogether 1 
                         -pvx 0 -pvy 0 -pvz 4.0 
                          $outName` ;
 $outNameExtrude = $tmp[0];
```

This saves you form Maya blowing up in your face. So your code would look like:

```
proc makeCubesDrivenBy(
    string $controlName, int $totalObjects, float $spacing
    ){

    for($i=1;$i<=$totalObjects;$i++)
    {
        string $tmp[];
        string $outName = ("twist_"+ $i);   
        string $outNameExtrude = ("ext_"+$i);
        float $extrusion = 0;

        $tmp = `polyCube -n $outName -ch 1
                 -o on -w 12.009218 
                 -h 7.720124 -d 0.755927
                 -cuv 4`;
        $outname = $tmp[0];
        setAttr ($outName+".translateZ") ($spacing*$i);  

        $tmp = `polyExtrudeFacet -n $outNameExtrude
                                 -ch 1 
                                 -keepFacesTogether 1 
                                 -pvx 0 -pvy 0 -pvz 4.0 
                                 $outName` ;
        $outNameExtrude = $tmp[0];
        setAttr ($outNameExtrude + ".localTranslate") 
                  -type double3 0 $extrusion 0 ;


        expression -s ( $outNameExtrude + ".tz" +
                        "= Rotator.rotateY * 0.01*" +
                       ($i*0.5) + ";")  -o "" 
                       -ae 0 -uc all ;
    }
}

{
    string $pipe[], $facet[];
    int $totalObjects = 1; 
    $pipe = `polyPipe -n Rotator -ch 1 
             -o on -r 1.839239 
             -h 1.223879` ;
    $facet = `polyExtrudeFacet -ch 1 -keepFacesTogether 1
                     -pvx 0.07364761256 
                     -pvy 0.6119394158 
                     -pvz 4.019784712 
                     -divisions 1 -twist 0 
                     -taper 1 -off 0 
                     -smoothingAngle 30 Rotator.f[36]`;
    setAttr ($facet[0] + ".localTranslate") 
            -type double3 0 0 0.930651 ;
    makeCubesDrivenBy($pipe[0], 1 , 1.5);
}
```

Anyway the process itself isnt really sane as you copy history inputs but I can not really guess what you are after.

PS: dont use -ae 1 in expressions unless you really have to, and you dont.

Answer (score 1):

Your expression is

```
0= Rotator.rotateY * 0.01*0.5;
```

which doesn't work. Do you want   ".O[0]"  instead ?

You also have a -r flag in your polyExtrudeFacet; I don't think that works.

Finally, you should bracket $outNameExtrude + ".localTranslate" in the last line;

Comment: Well I just need to manipulate the LocalTranslateY, so I thought using $extrusion would assign it a value, but I suppose not. I updated my code can you please look over it again. The error I am getting now is :  setAttr: No object matches name: ext_1.localTranslate

Comment: It looks like you are relying on the extrusion being named $outNameExtrude -- but that's not guaranteed, if there is already something with that name in the scene. You should catch the result of the PolyExtrudeFacet in a variable and set the value on that variable, not $outNameExtrude

Comment: I see, I am sorry I am very new to this and have no idea on how would I do that. I would really appreciate if you can show me?

Comment: string `$extrudeNode = polyExtrudeFacet -n $outNameExtrude -constructionHistory 1 -keepFacesTogether 1 -pvx 0 -pvy 0 -pvz 4.0 $outName` ;
setAttr ($extrudeNode + ".localTranslate") -type double3 0 $extrusion 0 ;